# Running calculation in SQL query

Tags: sql, db2

I have a table that contains a list of numbers:

```
select SERIAL, CHANGE from TABLE
```

I get this result:

```
1    35
2    10
3    -3
4     2
5     9
```

Now I want to do a running total, starting with a number gotten from another query, say:

```
select NUMBER from NUMBERLIST
```

say NUMBER is 44. I want to construct a query that gives me:

```
0     0    44
1    35    79
2    10    89
3    -3    86
4     2    88
5     9    97
```

Is that doable in SQL?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is doable, but I'm not too sure of the results you want to see.

This for example:

```
SELECT COLUMN1, (COLUMN1 + 44) as 'COLUMN2' FROM NUMBERLIST
```

Should give you two column results. The first containing the original data. The second containing original data + 44 which we also named 'COLUMN2'.

If you wanted to just see the data + 44 then:

```
SELECT (COLUMN1 + 44) as 'COLUMN NAME' FROM NUMBERLIST
```

I just realised you want to add from a number from another query. In this instance you would need a nested select. e.g.:

```
SELECT (SELECT NUMBER FROM TABLE) as 'COLUMN1', ((SELECT NUMBER FROM TABLE) + 44) AS 'COLUMN2'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
  SERIAL
, DECODE (SERIAL, 0, 0, CHANGE) AS CHANGE
, SUM (CHANGE) OVER (ORDER BY SERIAL) AS CHANGE_TOTAL
FROM
(
  SELECT SERIAL, CHANGE
  FROM 
  /*
  (
  VALUES
    (1, 35)
  , (2, 10)
  , (3, -3)
  , (4,  2)
  , (5,  9)
  ) 
  */
  TABLE --(SERIAL, CHANGE)
  
    UNION ALL

  SELECT 0 AS SERIAL, NUMBER AS CHANGE 
  FROM 
  --(VALUES 44) 
  NUMBERLIST 
  --(NUMBER)
)
```

If you uncomment the commented out lines, you may run the statement as is and get the following result:

| SERIAL | CHANGE | CHANGE_TOTAL |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 44 |
| 1 | 35 | 79 |
| 2 | 10 | 89 |
| 3 | -3 | 86 |
| 4 | 2 | 88 |
| 5 | 9 | 97 |

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by union the two queries together and then cumulative summation using the function sum()  over() :

```
select id , val , SUM(val) over( order by id) As SumVal from (
select 0 As id , number As val from NUMBERLIST
union 
select id , val from Table_1 ) T
```

The first function or query must return only one line.

the result

[image]